# Behavior to update a computed binding in Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to create a behavior that adds a computed property to the element it augments.

Example Template:

```html
<template>
    <span>[[getLight(0)]]</span><br />
    <span>[[getLight(1)]]</span><br />
    <span>[[getLight(2)]]</span><br />
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'vertical-light',
        behaviors: [
            stopLightBehavior
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Example Behavior:

```js
//Located in another file, with its implementation obscured
stopLightBehavior = {
    ready: function() {
        this._myArray = [true, false, false];

        setInterval(function() {
            this.unshift('_myArray', this.pop('_myArray'));

            // getLight needs to be updated!

        }.bind(this), 500);
    },

    getLight: function(index) {
        return this._myArray[index];
    }
};
```

In the above example, the values like `getLight(0)` never get updated because they don't reference `_myArray.*`. However, I don't want the users of the behavior to have to enumerate the dependencies of `getLight` every time. Is it possible to tell Polymer exactly when `getLight` needs to be updated?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to force a computed binding to update without changing the value of any of its parameters. If what you're trying to do is to have some sort of path of an n number of lights which "moves" to the left then I think you're better off using a [`dom-repeat`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-repeat) instead of computed bindings

Comment: The example above is strictly for illustration. My actual use-case involves watching `getEffectiveChildren()` using `observeNodes` and various properties of the children, and then updating an array when they change.